Swift Combine: Managing Multiple Threads with AnyPublisher and PassthroughSubject
I have some Combine streams that I am merging together to create some state for a feature I'm building. Will spare the details, but the basic gist of this is that the main stream is responsible for accumulating elements from sub-streams with scan(_:). The problematic sub-stream is driven by a PassthroughSubject that's called from somewhere else in my app. In reality, there's more happening in the sub-stream that isn't important, this is just an example.
I'd expect that if I fire events off into the subject from multiple threads, the accumulation in the main stream will be incorrect because of the fact that the Combine can run on whatever thread it wants (and from what I understand, scan(_:) is not inherently thread safe).
If I use receive(on:) in my streams I would expect the accumulation in my main stream to work correctly, but I'm still seeing events being handled out of order.
So far, I've tried putting a receive(on:) in my sub stream where I listen to the subject. I've also tried adding different attributes to this operator like barrier with no affect. I've also tried having putting a lock around the subject which was pointless since subjects handle locking themselves. See below for some code:
struct MainStream {
    enum MainEvent {
        case start
        case setCount(Int)
    }

    struct MainState: Equatable {
        var count: Int
    }

    let queue: DispatchQueue
    let subInteractor: SubStream

    func build(_ upstream: AnyPublisher<MainEvent, Never>) -> AnyPublisher<MainState, Never> {
        let shared = upstream.share().eraseToAnyPublisher()
        let subStream = subInteractor
            .build(
                shared
                    .map { _ in SubStream.SubEvent.observe }
                    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            )
            .map { state in MainEvent.setCount(state.count) }

        return shared
            .merge(with: subStream)
            .scan(MainState(count: 0)) { accum, event in
                switch event {
                case .start:
                    return accum
                case let .setCount(int):
                    return MainState(count: int)
                }
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

struct SubStream {
    struct SubState {
        let count: Int
    }

    enum SubEvent {
        case observe
    }

    let queue: DispatchQueue
    let subject: PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>

    func build(_ upstream: AnyPublisher<SubEvent, Never>) -> AnyPublisher<SubState, Never> {
        upstream
            .map { event in
                // in production code we respond to the closed over
                // `event`, but not important for this example
                subject
                    .receive(on: queue)
                    .map { int in
                        SubState(count: int)
                    }
            }
            .switchToLatest()
            .receive(on: queue)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

and here is a unit test that simulates multiple threads:

    var sut: MainStream!

    ... test setup functions

    func test_multipleThreads() {
        let expectation0 = XCTestExpectation(description: #function)

        let expectation1 = XCTestExpectation(description: "expectation1")
        let expectation2 = XCTestExpectation(description: "expectation2")
        let expectation3 = XCTestExpectation(description: "expectation3")

        let queue1 = DispatchQueue(label: "queue1")
        let queue2 = DispatchQueue(label: "queue2")
        let queue3 = DispatchQueue(label: "queue3")

        let expectedResults = [0, 1, 2, 3]
        var receivedOutput: [Int] = []

        sut.build(subject.eraseToAnyPublisher())
            .collect(4)
            .sink { output in
                receivedOutput = output.map { $0.count }
                expectation0.fulfill()
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)

        subject.send(.setCount(0))
        queue1.async { [self] in
            interactorSubject.send(1)
            expectation1.fulfill()
        }
        queue2.async { [self] in
            interactorSubject.send(2)
            expectation2.fulfill()
        }
        queue3.async { [self] in
            interactorSubject.send(3)
            expectation3.fulfill()
        }

        wait(for: [expectation0, expectation1, expectation2, expectation3], timeout: 0.5)
        XCTAssertEqual(receivedOutput, expectedResults)
    }

The test above rarely passes (~40 times out of 100) so I'm assuming that there's some threading stuff I am not understanding fully here.
Thanks.

Your test is failing because 3 is being sent into the publisher before 2 is by the OS. This isn't something you can "fix" through any publisher method.

@DanielT. thanks for responding. what makes you come to that conclusion? All values are sent on different queues so I'm not sure how we can be certain that 2 is coming after 3.

Exactly my point. You don't have any control over what order the values will be sent in, so expecting to receive them in a specific order is inappropriate.

@DanielT. thanks - I think I am starting to understand why this is happening. One more question: I thought that the receive(on:) operator was supposed to serialize event receiving in a combine stream? Am I misunderstanding how that operator is working?

Event receiving in a stream is serialized by default. IE, all the methods that produce values must not emit a value until the downstream has finished processing the previous value. This is part of the contract. You basically don't need to use receive(on:) unless the side effects in the downstream methods must occur on a particular thread. This is why a sink(receiveValue:) is often preceded by a receive(on: RunLoop.main) or some such. The receive(on:) method accepts an event and then re-emits it on the thread used by the provided Scheduler.
